# configuring FastCGI on CentOS with PHP

Tags: php, centos, fastcgi

So I was following [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-install-configure-nginx-php5/) tutorial, but then I was stuck because when running the code:

```
# yum install spawn-fcgi
```

it says there is no package. I am using Nginx.
Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on EPEL repo:

```
 rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

then install spawn-fcgi:

```
 yum install spawn-fcgi
```

Comment: and this would replace that yum command for spawn-fcgi?

Comment: I got this error:


Retrieving http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
error: skipping http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
warning: u 0x1f876d0 ctrl 0x1f88a40 nrefs != 0 (download.fedora.redhat.com http)

Comment: rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm then yum install spawn-fcgi

Comment: when I try to download this script:

# wget http://bash.cyberciti.biz/dl/419.sh.zip

seems that it just won't do it, saying no data received

Comment: curl http://bash.cyberciti.biz/dl/419.sh.zip > 419.sh.zip

Comment: I did that, sorry for the delay

Comment: for i386 
http://epel.mirror.net.in/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS 6.2 x64 I used this:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
```

I found that repository here:

http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

---Update July 2012

CentOS 6.2 32bit this worked for me:

```
rpm -ivh http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
yum install spawn-fcgi
```

---Update March 2013

CentOS 6.2 64bit Linode:

```
rpm -ivh http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install spawn-fcgi
```

For future reference, this link might be helpful:
[How to enable "EPEL" repository for centos?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384855/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-centos)