# How to enable "EPEL" repository for centos?

Tags: linux, installation

I'm trying to install couchdb, but failed installing from source.

I see in the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_RHEL5), it says if I "enable the EPEL repository", that I can just use `yum install couchdb` to install.

But I'm new to linux, what does "Enable the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository" mean? My linux is <del>Fedora 16</del> Centos 6.2.

Comment: couchdb should be generally available in Fedora 16.  You should be able to just run "yum install couchdb".  The instructions you're looking at are for RHEL/CentOS, which are not the same as Fedora.

Comment: Sorry, I just found my linux is centos 6.2 -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install this rpm

```
rpm -ivh http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
yum update
yum install couchdb
```

** epel-release on mirror has changed to 6-7

Answer (score 6):

EPEL, or Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux, is [a yum repository designed to offer some packages from Fedora and other places to Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#What_is_Extra_Packages_for_Enterprise_Linux_.28or_EPEL.29.3F), and therefore also to CentOS.  It's not suitable for use on a Fedora system, sorry.

To follow up on cjc's comment, above, he's right.  I'm running F16 on my desktop, and `yum install` seems to find everything it needs right there in the Fedora repository:

```
[root@risby ez-pine-gpg]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 16 (Verne)
[root@risby ez-pine-gpg]# yum install couchdb
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
[...many lines removed...]
Dependencies Resolved

==================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                            Arch                               Version                                         Repository                            Size
==================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 couchdb                                            i686                               1.0.3-2.fc16                                    fedora                               533 k
Installing for dependencies:
 erlang-compiler                                    i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               984 k
 erlang-crypto                                      i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                                51 k
 erlang-erts                                        i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               1.4 M
 erlang-et                                          i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               198 k
 erlang-eunit                                       i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               139 k
 erlang-gs                                          i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               606 k
 erlang-hipe                                        i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               1.0 M
 erlang-ibrowse                                     i686                               2.2.0-4.fc16                                    fedora                                96 k
 erlang-inets                                       i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               755 k
 erlang-kernel                                      i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               1.0 M
 erlang-mnesia                                      i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               663 k
 erlang-mochiweb                                    i686                               1.4.1-5.fc16                                    fedora                               338 k
 erlang-oauth                                       i686                               1.0.1-2.fc15                                    fedora                                27 k
 erlang-observer                                    i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               206 k
 erlang-public_key                                  i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               396 k
 erlang-runtime_tools                               i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               211 k
 erlang-sasl                                        i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               268 k
 erlang-ssl                                         i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               379 k
 erlang-stdlib                                      i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               2.2 M
 erlang-syntax_tools                                i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               324 k
 erlang-tools                                       i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               536 k
 erlang-webtool                                     i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                                45 k
 erlang-wx                                          i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               2.5 M
 erlang-xmerl                                       i686                               R14B-04.1.fc16                                  fedora                               940 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+24 Dependent packages)
```

Comment: You both right, my linux is actually centos 6.2, not Fedora ...